# Does it exist an enhanced Toolbar for matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, toolbar

I'm looking for a toolbar for matplotlib figure that contains more options than the basic one, which is automatically set in pyqt environment.

[image]

I already know how to add my own button, but I'm looking for a more advanced Toolbar already coded, that I can used directly.
In Matlab, for instance, it is possible to add points in the panel, or a text directly on the figure from the figure itself.

Answer (score 1):

Outside of the one you're using, I don't think so. Try [bokeh](https://bokeh.org/). Depending on your environment, [ipywidgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) may work too.

Hope that helps!